# How to create a new dataframe from another one where cells (not entire row/column) not meeting certain condition are eliminated

Tags: dataframe

How to delete the cells in the df below based on the following condition:
- If Size_2 - Size_1 <= 2 and Height_2 <= Height_1, then delete Size_2 and Height_2

| Sample | Size_1 | Height_1 | Size_2 | Height_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 120 | 12 | 110 |
| B | 12 | 150 | 20 | 140 |
| C | 14 | 170 | 15 | 160 |
| D | 16 | 180 | 22 | 150 |

the output will look like this:

| Sample | Size_1 | Height_1 | Size_2 | Height_2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 10 | 120 |  |  |
| B | 12 | 150 | 20 | 140 |
| C | 14 | 170 |  |  |
| D | 16 | 180 | 22 | 150 |

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a mask:

```
df.loc[(df["Size_2"] - df["Size_1"] <= 2) & (df["Height_2"] <= df["Height_1"]), ["Size_2", "Height_2"]] = np.NAN
```

Note that you can replace the `np.NAN` with anything you want.